# How to set token permissions in Facebook php SDK using code?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I started using php sdk of Facebook and I generated an access token using the Graph API Explorer and I set all the permissions there.

Now I use that token in my code like:

```php
\FacebookAds\Api::init(config('facebook.app_id'), config('facebook.app_secret'), config('facebook.access_token, false);
\FacebookAds\Api::instance();
```

After 60 days (the expire time of a "long lived" token) I face the issue that my token is not valid anymore.

Is there a way to generate a token by code and grant him the required permissions. In my case:

- The lead_retrieval permission
- The pages_manage_metadata permission
- The pages_show_list permission

Comment: _"Is there a way to generate a token by code and grant him the required permissions."_ - the point of OAuth is, that is requires user interaction - so, no. But within the marketing API realm, there are system and business users, and those have different rules regarding token expiry, I think.

Comment: The point of an auth system is that a user grants itself permission? That should never be the case in any auth system. Permissions should be granted from higher order

Comment: The user does not grant themselves permission, they grant it to your app.

Comment: So "Create a token with lead_retrieval permission" is not possible?

Comment: Of course it is, by implementing the login flow.

Comment: And this is possible by code or only with the UI? I don't find anything about the permission granting in the Facebook docs

Comment: Only via UI, that's what I meant when I said "requires user interaction". The general process to manually implement the server-side login flow is explained under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/guides/advanced/manual-flow, the regular Graph API PHP SDK also has methods for that. (Not sure if the Business SDK also implements those.)

Comment: Or you implement the client-side login flow, and then pass the token from the client to the server. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

Comment: That would not work for my use case. I have a webhook in place that adds leads to my app's database. The webhook runs as a service on a server without any user interaction. I manually created a token that is required to initiate the API and use the `LeadgenForm` object. But the need to manually update the token all x days makes the service useless.

Comment: But processing the incoming webhook data itself does not require a token, only the setup part does, AFAIK? I don't actually now if the webhook would stop working, just because the token that was initially used to set it up, has expired ... as long as the user who's token was used, does not _revoke_ the permissions granted to the app, I would assume that not to be the case.

Comment: Unfortunately the webhook does not send the actual lead from's field data (what I need), it sends the leadgen_id and I get the data using `(new \FacebookAds\Object\LeadgenForm($leadgen_id))->getSelf()->getData()['field_data']`. For that I need a valid token. After 60 days I got `Error validating access token: Session has expired`

Comment: See if using a system users works for you then, I think their tokens do not expire. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/system-users And if that is not the case - well then you might have to set up a system that notifies someone and has them generate a new token, when the 60 days have passed. (And if no one is around who could be bothered to do that ... well then the interest in that lead data can't be all to serious in the first place, I suppose :-) )